# Win 7 32 matplotlib dateutil

Tags: python, matplotlib

I just installed the following onto my Win 7 machine running an AMD A8-5600K APU (64-bit Operating System

```
python-2.7.6.msi
matplotlib-1.3.1.win32-py2.7.exe
numpy-1.8.0-win32-superpack-python2.7.exe
```

When I use

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
```

I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "C:\Python27\MuirsProgs\decay-1.py", line 9, in <module> 
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib_init_.py", line 111, in <module> 
    raise ImportError("matplotlib requires dateutil") 
ImportError: matplotlib requires dateutil
```

I am new to Python and have no idea of how to fix this.

Comment: your error message does not match the code you gave. Did you `import matplotlib` before running `help(matplotlib)`?

Comment: @MattDMo  I don't know where the above error message came from.  Here is the entire message I get when I run the program:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\MuirsProgs\decay-1.py", line 9, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 111, in <module>
    raise ImportError("matplotlib requires dateutil")
ImportError: matplotlib requires dateutil

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you examine the **actual** error message you got, you'll see that `matplotlib` requires the `dateutil` module. It actually requires a few other modules as well, and has optional dependencies on several more. The easiest way to install many scientific computing and other modules on Windows is to visit Christoph Gohlke's excellent [Python Extension Packages for Windows](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) repository and have a look around to see if your module of interest is there. Many of them are linked to a version of `NumPy` compiled with Intel's [Math Kernel Library](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl/) (MKL) for increased performance.

If you go down to the [`matplotlib`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#matplotlib) section, you'll find the list of required and optional dependencies, including `numpy`, `dateutil`, `pytz`, `pyparsing`, and `six`. I'd also recommend getting `Pillow` and `tornado` as well as your favorite graphics backend (I use `pyqt`). Just follow the links to the other sections of the repository, and download the appropriate files for your version and bit-ness of Python. I'd recommend re-downloading the MKL-linked `NumPy` installer, even though you have an AMD processor, as many of the other packages rely on it, and it will gracefully degrade if your particular processor doesn't have all the features an Intel one might. I'd also recommend re-downloading the `matplotlib` installer as well, just so all your modules have come from the same source, and will play together as nicely as possible. If you want to, beforehand, go to `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages` and delete the `numpy` and `matplotlib` directories, as well as any other files/directories with related names. If you haven't installed any other third-party modules at all except those two, then just delete all contents of the `site-packages` directory and you should be fine.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  I started from scratch following your suggestions and now my program works!

Comment: I installed python 2.7 to "C:\Python27\" then cd to "C:\Python27\Scripts" then installed all required packages with this command "pip.exe install <package name>"